# Pandas - sorting dataframe by two columns that one of them uses key

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AmirForooghi/stocks_example/main/xxx.csv')
```

I want to sort df by two columns: rsi and sector. For rsi I want `ascending=False` and for sector I want to use the `key` argument. The key is:

```
order_dic = {j: i for i, j in enumerate(['bank', 'naft', 'pey'])}
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
df = df.loc[df.sector.isin(['bank', 'naft', 'pey'])]  # just to clean the data a little bit
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by='rsi', ascending=False).sort_values(by='sector', key=lambda x:x.map(order_dic))
```

But it doesn't work. it is sorted by the key correctly but it is not sorted by rsi.

Comment: what's your expected output? Can you be more specific on exactly what doesn't work

Comment: @el_oso I want to sort it by two columns. If you run my code you can see that it is sorted by the key correctly but it is not sorted by rsi anymore

Comment: can you edit the question to include the output you get and the output you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a stable sorting algorithm to preserve the order of the first sort. You can do this by setting `kind='mergesort'`

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by='rsi', ascending=False).sort_values(by='sector', key=lambda x:x.map(order_dic), kind='mergesort')
```